# Where's the mistake in my solution to a related rates problem?

Tags: derivatives, volume, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

I'm currently taking MAT 265 in Arizona State online and came across this problem:

Water is leaking out of an inverted conical tank at a rate of $6700.0$  cubic centimeters per minute at the same time that water is being pumped into the tank at a constant rate. The tank has height $14.0$  meters and the diameter at the top is $5.0$ meters. If the water level is rising at a rate of $16.0$  centimeters per minute when the height of the water is $3.0$  meters, find the rate at which water is being pumped into the tank in cubic centimeters per minute.

My thought process is like so:

1. Change in volume can be described in terms of leaking and pumping of the water

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=R-0.0067\frac{m^3}{min}$$

2. It can also be described in terms of the conic volume formula:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \pi \cdot \left(2\cdot r\cdot \frac{dr}{dt}\cdot h+r^2\cdot \frac{dh}{dt}\right)$$

We don't know $\frac{dr}{dt}$, however we can use the chain rule and rewrite it as $\frac{dr}{dh}\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}$. Now, if we imagine an inverted conic, as we go up from the tip to the base at constant speed, radius also grows linearly, so $\frac{dr}{dh}$ is the average change over the whole height, so

$$\frac{dr}{dh}=\frac{5-0}{14-0}=\frac{5}{14}$$
Also, $r$ in this case becomes:
$$r=h\cdot\frac{dr}{dh}=3\cdot\frac{5}{14}=\frac{15}{14}m$$
3. With that information we simplify, equate two definitions of $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and solve for R.
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \pi \cdot \left(2\cdot r\cdot \frac{dr}{dh}\cdot \frac{dh}{dt}\cdot h+r^2\cdot \frac{dh}{dt}\right)$$
$$R-0.0067=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\left(2\cdot r\cdot\frac{dr}{dh}\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\cdot h+r^2\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\right)$$
$$R=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\left(2\cdot r\cdot\frac{dr}{dh}\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\cdot h+r^2\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\right)+0.0067$$
$$R=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\left(2\cdot \frac{15}{14}\cdot\frac{5}{14}\cdot0.16\cdot 3+\left(\frac{15}{14}\right)^2\cdot0.16\right)+0.0067$$
$$R=0.58372722\frac{m^3}{min}=583727.22\frac{cm^3}{min}$$

However, this doesn't seem like the correct answer and there's certainly something wrong here. What am I missing and what would be the correct solution?

Comment: Can you articulate why doesn't this seem like the correct solution to you? If you emailed this post to your professor what do you think they would say/suggest?

Comment: I'm using gradarius, it just says that it is wrong. I don't have an assigned professor, so I've nowhere to turn outside of such forums

Comment: Well one error is that they gave you the diameter at the top, not the radius at the top, so $dr/dh$ is actually $2.5/14$.

Comment: Thx, that was the issue